# Multiple Values while scraping in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, web-scraping

So I'm trying to retrieve some values from a website in node js and it's giving me repetitive values and I was wondering how to filter values as to show only one instance of the repetitive values as to display only the value I want.

**The Output I want to display**
`'JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA'`

**The Code**

The variable hospitaladdress gives me the mentioned output

```
    var hospital = $(this).text()
    var govthospitalnames = hospital.replace('(Government Hospital)','').trim()

    var refinegovthospitalnames = govthospitalnames.replace('(Satellite Govt. Building)','').trim()
    if(hospital.includes("Government") || hospital.includes("Govt.")){
         var hospitalstatus = "Government Hospital"
         var hospitaladdress = $('div[class="card-text col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"]').text().replace(/\s+/g,'').trim()
         console.log(hospitaladdress)
        }
```

**The Output**

````
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREAStreetNumber299,DJBlock(Newtown),ActionAreaI,Newtown,NewTown,WestBengal700156,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA578BarrackporeTrunkRoadKAMARHATIKolkata-700058,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA54BagmariRoad,Kolkata54,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREASealdah,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA57,BeleghataMainRd,SubhasSarobarPark,PhoolBagan,Beleghata,Kolkata,WestBengal700010,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA241,DeshpranSasmalRd,Netajinagar,RajendraPrasadColony,Tollygunge,Kolkata,WestBengal700033,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA88,CollegeSt,CalcuttaMedicalCollege,CollegeSquare,Kolkata,WestBengal700073,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA138,AcharyaJagadishChandraBoseRd,Sealdah,RajaBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700014,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA1,KhudiramBoseSarani,BidhanSarani,ShyamBazar,Kolkata,WestBengal700004,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA```
````

Answer (score 0):

This code lacks context. Is it inside a loop? Where's the source of the data you're displaying?

Generally, you should use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store all the strings you have seen so far, and whenever you need to add a new string and do some operations on it check that it doesn't exist already

Comment: It's from a website that gives hospitals info,I tried using set but it doesn't work still gives me redundant values

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I see the problem now. Your selector must be selecting more than one element. Try using a more specific selector or select just the first element, like
`var hospitaladdress = $('div[class="card-text col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"]')[0].text().replace(/\s+/g,'').trim()`

Comment: `TypeError: $(...)[0].text is not a function` it's returning this error

Comment: Sorry again, my jQuery is rusty...I think it should be `.first()` instead of `[0]`.

Comment: ```JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
JBBlock,SectorIII,Bidhannagar,Kolkata,WestBengal700098,KOLKATAMETROPOLITANAREA
```